# In Hinduism, what does "immortal" mean? Is there a limit on an immortal's lifespan?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, atma

I would like to clarify that this question is **not** about immortals, or about how to become an immortal. It is about the word *immortal* in Hinduism.

We have a very brief idea, that an immortal is only a supreme being and we know one day the whole universe will end. Therefore it is clear that no one is truly immortal (as they speak in English).

What I actually wanted to ask is what is the limit of an immortal's life? a *Yuga*, a *Mahayuga*, a *Kalpa* or something larger? If my assumption is true, do these vary with every immortal?

Comment: Question would be best rephrased as "What are the different life spans in beings in the universe?" It's pointless to say someone is immortal if they have a lifespan. If you're using "immortal" as a phrase, it's just confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Immortal is brahman. So lifespan of someone who has attained brahman is that of brahman. And this is not containable or measurable using our physical frames of reference for time or space.

Lord Dattatreya says to not even bother attempting to understand the beginning of time and creation. Sage VyAsa says the same in the brahma sUtrAs. Therefore, it is inferred that the magnitude is immeasurable using our earthly  units of physics.

You may also refer to Upanishad slOkas that are chanted before prostrating in front of a yatIswara. They indicate that the state of brahman is beyond the wordly realm. They start as "na karmaNA , na prajaya, dhanEna, tyAgEnaikE amRtatva mAnusuhu".

Here is one [link](http://chinmayabirmingham.org/sites/default/files/images/InitialPrayers.pdf) to the chant and its translation. Look at the table on page 1.

Comment: I liked the way you started, I would love to have a descriptive answer from you, please help. Your answer seems more like a direction not path.

Comment: @Mr.K Your question was about the length of an immortal's life and I am trying to say that it is immeasurable because of what immortal means. If you can tell me what else you are looking for, perhaps I can help some more.

Comment: I got what you want to say, but the facts you quoted from scriptures if you can put them here, with the translation, that would mean a lot and will make the answer good. You are new to hinduismSE,which is in beta stage, we love descriptive answers and this makes the content look good.

Answer (score 4):

Super soul (God) and Jivatman (individual soul) are both immortal. However our physical, material bodies are not immortal. In fact nothing in material world is immortal nor it is supposed to be. And once the material universes end the new cycle of creation will begin. There is no permanent end in the Eternal Religion. Cycles of creation and dissolution of material universes will go on. At the time of dissolution of material universes those souls are still not disturbed who have already attained moksha because they are already in Golok Vrindavan or Vainkunth, the abode of God. And when material universes are annihilated the abode of Lord is still untouched and unchanged and eternally blissful as Krishna says:

> "When Brahma's day is manifest, this multitude of living entities comes into being, and at the arrival of Brahma's night they are all annihilated." - Bhagwad Gita (chapter 8, verse 18)
>
> "Again and again the day comes, and this host of beings is active; and again the night falls, O Partha, and they are helplessly dissolved." - Bhagwad Gita (chapter 8, verse 19)
>
> "Yet there is another nature, which is eternal and is transcendental to this manifested and unmanifested matter. It is supreme and is never annihilated. When all in this universe is annihilated, that part remains as it is." - Bhagwad Gita (chapter 8, verse 20)
>
> "That supreme abode is called unmanifested and infallible, and it is the supreme destination. When one goes there, he never comes back. That is My supreme abode."
>   - Bhagwad Gita (chapter 8, verse 21)

Now question arises what happens to those souls at the time of dissolution of material universes who have not attained liberation from material existence? Such souls enter God in deep sleep but obviously their material bodies are dissolved and awakened again when new cycle of creation begins in new material bodies. And one more thing is when individual souls enter God they don't lose their existence. They remain in unmanifested and impersonal God but maintain their individuality.

So in short the Super Soul and individual soul both are immortal.

Answer (score 4):

There can be two context I can refer immortality

1)Soul Context

2)Bodily Context

In Soul context every soul is immortal .It is never born and never going to die.

Bodily context, Immortalism can equate to either chiranjeevi or amara in hinduism.
Chiranjeevi is someone who is long living. Amara is the one who is deathless.We all know about samdra manthan and people who could drink nector  became amara.

But amara  jeevas are NOT deathless . They live up to end of manvantara.
Chiranjeevis would live until end of time.

Comment: Good answer, but can you add some sources for 'amara jeevas are NOT deathless', 'Chiranjeevi is someone who is long living' etc.?