# How concept of Moksha and Amar (Immortality) can exists together?

Tags: moksha, rebirth

**Moksha** - Once you are dead you'll get rid of Life Cycle (Jeevan Chakra), you become an absolute and pure energy traveling across the Universe. No need to reincarnate again, take birth as Fly or Human or any other form.

**Amarta (Immortality):** You remain young forever. You will never die.

Lord Hanuman, who is Lord Shiva's avatar is immortal, why he didn't try for Moksha?

Should we pray for Moksha or Immortality?

Comment: "No need to reincarnate again" -it seems half truth to me...if world needs someone then they hv to reincarnate...we hv plenty of examples where the great ascetics, yogis, saints, kings and rishis reincarnated...even this site is full of Q-A where people say he was reincarnation of that individual...

Comment: "Should we pray for Moksha or Immortality?"- none of the two...Hanuman, Vibhishan didn't try for immortality...Many people tried for immortality but didn't get, they were rejected...most of the immortals didn't try for it...they got it as the reward of their good actions...if one do Dharma, Artha, Kama in balanced way then Moksha or Immortality is the result...there r very few (or no) instances where someone asked for immortality or moksha in pray/boon and were granted..

Comment: Amarta - Bodily immortality (According to your definition)
Moksha - Realizing that you are not the body
When you are not the body what's the point of attaining bodily immortality (unless you want to serve the Lord forever in the same body).

Comment: Visit [In Hinduism, what does “immortal” mean? Is there a limit on an immortal's lifespan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2899/277)

Comment: @YDS how come immortality is a reward when Moksha is the prime goal and more blissful than life itself.

Comment: @iammilind I dont think so. I am fully aware what is vardaan, boon, amartva. I just wanted to know which onefrom the two, living beings seek for.

Comment: @yds no it is not related because as per me only one of two should exist not both. I am sure they are not related, so I am not asking that.

Comment: "Should we pray for Moksha or Immortality?" If you behave morally only for reward, have you actually behaved morally? Perform your dharma without focusing on the fruits of your actions.

Answer (score 2):

According to Bhagavad Gita, ***Moksha* (liberation) and *Amaratva* (immortality) are same**.

From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20461/1049), for liberation & immortality -- happiness-Sorrow or any duality is same.

> BG 2.15 - O foremost of men, surely all these don't distress to that person(*Purusha*); that wise person to whom **sorrow and happhiness are the same -- is fit for immortality**.
>   BG 6.7 - The conqueror of the own self, quite pacified [person] **establishes with supreme Self (viz. liberates) in** heat-cold, **sorrow-happiness**, and honour-dishonour

Besides, you may also combine below verses to confirm that both are same.

> BG 8.16 - All planes along with BrahM-plane are repetitive, O Arjuna. But O son of Kunti, **reaching "Me", the rebirth doesn't happen**.
>   BG 9.19 - O Arjuna, I give heat, I withhold and pour the rains. **the immortality is "Me"**, and also death, existent and nonexistent.

The meanings of liberation and immortality are also combined in a verse:

> BG 2.20 - **"That" is neither born nor die**; Nor having come to exist, "That" will again cease to be. "That" is **birthless**, eternal, **undecaying**, ancient; It is not killed when the body is killed.

---

> > *"Moksha - Once you are dead you'll get rid of Life Cycle (Jeevan Chakra), you become an absolute and pure energy traveling across the Universe"*

**No**, not quite true. If after liberation one "becomes" an energy of whatever form, then that means it's still existing. In other words, that entity has taken a rebirth in form of an energy.
Any existence is directly orthogonal to liberation. :-)

> > *"Amarta (Immortality): You remain young forever. You will never die."*

**No**. As already stated above, those who are born are meant to decay followed by death and those who die are meant to take rebirth.

> BG 2.27 - Those who have a birth, it's certain [for them] to die, For dead, certainly there will be a [re]birth; Hence you don't have to grieve about inevitable

Until a being relates themselves with bodily aspects, they keep taking births.

> > *"Lord Hanuman, who is Lord Shiva's avatar is immortal, why he didn't try for Moksha?"*

**No**. Lord Hanuman is not immortal. He is a *Cheeranjivi* (long lived). There are various posts on that topic in our site.

*Moksha* is not something to be tried or achieved, it's received or attained, once a person becomes totally indifferent to everything in the worldly aspects. Until the gods like Shri Hanuman have certain role to play or duty to perform, they may not give up their physical self.

> > *"Should we pray for Moksha or Immortality?"*

**None**. Anyways both are same.

If we pray to get "something", then we have to stay till that "something" is attained. Hence, until we have some purpose to fulfil, Moksha is not attainable.
Desires (viz. to achieve something) & Anti-desires (viz. to give up something), both keep us plugged with the material world in one or the other form.

Disinterest or indifference, eventually leads to liberation.
Refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20243/1049).

Comment: your answer is pretty close to my satisfaction, plus you also added verses. However, I want to some more time before accepting your answer.

Comment: Hi Milind, I have also written my answer below. But now I am seeing a notice that `Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.` The answer is best given based on my religion and knowledge I have because of it. The same can't be available in book or maybe it's available it's not with me. What should I do further to improvise my answer?

Comment: @Hemang, you have to cite sources from a 'Hindu' literature -- preferably a verifiable website, which supports your writings/philosophy more or less. Answers without any sources are not welcomed mostly, unless exceptional cases.

Comment: I'd rather say, answers **should** quote sacred or scholarly texts. Those answers will be upvoted by the community. I don't know that it's accurate to say unsourced answers are *unwelcome*. I'd prefer to hear folk knowledge (i.e., information passed on for at least 3 generations) and weigh it accordingly to not even knowing about it in the first place. Multiple answers from multiple perspectives paint a more accurate picture of what Hinduism is in practice, even if it isn't strictly scriptural. Having said that, folk knowledge should still be sourced, e.g. "(my grandmother told me as a child)"

Answer (score 0):

> Moksha - Once you are dead you'll get rid of Life Cycle (Jeevan Chakra), you become an absolute and pure energy traveling across the Universe. No need to reincarnate again, take birth as Fly or Human or any other form.

- This is not true. Moksha is totally based on the overall karma (good/bad) you did throughout your life. You rebirth in any form will decide based on all your good or bad deeds in your current birth.
- A good karma can lead our soul to the better places like rebirth as a human, will decide our family, where we gonna born, will have parents, will have a family, will have friends, a good life, a healthy body, have hands, legs, can speak, can see, can listen, can think, and just so many things.
- Likewise, the bad karma can lead our soul to the worst birthplaces like rebirth as a human, but will no have parents, will not have a family, will not have anything to eat, will not have a ceiling to live under, will not have a life, will not have a hand, or a leg, or a deaf, or will get older as an illitrate person, or more worst will get birth as any kind of animals/insects which are visible or not visible, which has a form or no forms, will birth/die in a fraction of seconds, or more worst place in a hell.

Moral – So if you have a good life today, you have hands to work by yourself, legs to walk by yourself, you can see the world, you can listen to the people, you can share your feelings by speaking to your friends and families. You have parents, do respect those people and things, this is you get because sometime somewhere in your previous births you were not like what you are today! After all your bad deeds converted by your good deeds to a better karma, you're eligible for what you have right now. Stop doing such things which may lead you to the worst life ahead.

> Amarta (Immortality): You remain young forever. You will never die.

- Amarta doesn't mean you will be young forever. It just means that you won't die. As you have given that blessing (Vardhan) of Amarta (immortality) you have to work for that cause.

> Lord Hanuman, who is Lord Shiva's avatar is immortal, why he didn't try for Moksha?

- Lord Shri Hanuman, they don't need to try for it since he had met Lord Shri Ram who is everything to him. The purpose of immortality is to take care of humankind in generations.

> Should we pray for Moksha or Immortality?

- We should pray that we will do good deeds for ourselves and if possible for the world.

Source to verification:
http://www.melbournejainsangh.org/Library-Catalogue/articles/karma/

Comment: You added Karma according to Jainism. Answers on the site should be from _Hinduism_ point of view. Jainism is not same as Hinduism.